# User Context VS Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Trying to weigh what pattern is better when making requests from a client to either pass the id of the user through or to directly access it from user context. User context is an injected scoped service and is automatically set at the beginning of the request and contains the user id of the user currently in context (logged in user).

Example:

```
//Controller

    [ActionName("Something")]
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<Response>> GetControllerMethod()
    {
        _myManager.DoSomething();
    }
    
//Manager

    public void DoSomething() 
    {
      _handler.ProcessSomething();
    }
    
//Handler

    public void ProcessSomething() 
    {
       var userId = _userContext.Id;
       //Make DB call here passing userId as a param for filtering
    }
```

The alternative is the pass it through via parameters

```
//Controller

    [ActionName("Something")]
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<Response>> GetControllerMethod()
    {
        _myManager.DoSomething(_userContext.Id);
    }
    
//Manager

    public void DoSomething(int userId) 
    {
      _handler.ProcessSomething(userId);
    }
    
//Handler

    public void ProcessSomething(int userId) 
    {
       //Make DB call here passing userId as a param for filtering
    }
```

In general is it better to access user context and pass it through methods or allow the scoped service to be injected anywhere and directly access the context.

Comment: How to pass that parameter around, is dependent on whether you consider this parameter to be data passing the application's punblic API or contextual or internally oriented data, as described [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/di-composition-models-primer/).

Answer (score 0):

If user context is accessible in every place in your application, than passing it's content through many layers would only made things more complicated. It’s totally fine to inject that directly to your processing layer. Leave the controller for actions related to communication purposes.